# Sencha Touch - Empty store after reloading/ refreshing app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am struggling to find ways how to preserve data to local storage but seems no luck on my side now. I can successfully add/ remove items in store however, whenever i try to refresh nor reload the page (google chrome) looks like no data found in store.

Here is my code:

Model: Pendingmodel.js

```
Ext.define('mysample.model.PendingModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'ALIAS'
        },
        {
            name: 'OBJECT'
        },
        {
            name: 'DATETIME'
        },
        {
            name: 'FIELDVALUE'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'PendingModelProxy'
    }
}
```

});

Store: Pendingstore.js

```
Ext.define('mysample.store.PendingStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'mysample.model.PendingModel'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'mysample.model.PendingModel',
    storeId: 'PendingStore'
}
```

});

Controller:

```
onDraftCommand: function (form, isTapped) {
    var isValid = true;
    var me = this, getForm = me.getLeadsView();

    var pendingItems = getForm.getValues();

    var cleanItems = getForm.getValues();
    cleanItems['reset'] = function() {
        for (var prop in this) {
            delete this['reset']; 
            delete this['eventParameter']; 
            this[prop] = '';
        }
    }

    if(isTapped == true && isValid == true) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Message', 'Are you sure you want to save this on draft?', function (btn) {
            switch (btn) {
                case 'yes':
                    var date = new Date(), id = date.getUTCMilliseconds();
                    var obj = {
                        'ALIAS': 'leadsview',
                        'OBJECT': 'Leads Form',
                        'id': id,
                        'DATETIME': date,
                        'FIELDVALUE': pendingItems,
                    };
                    console.log('Leads pending store');
                    console.log(obj);

                    Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('PendingStore').add(obj);
                    Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('PendingStore').sync();
                    console.log(Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('PendingStore'));

                    //clear form
                    cleanItems.reset();
                    getForm.setValues(cleanItems);
                    //Ext.getCmp('signatureField').removeImage();

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [identifier strategy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-identifier%29) inside your model as below.

```
Ext.define('mysample.model.PendingModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    identifier: 'uuid', // add this
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'PendingModelProxy'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the unique identifier in your model, like this:-

```
Ext.define('mysample.model.PendingModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
    'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
    ],
    config: {
        identifier: {
            type: 'uuid',
            isUnique: true
        },
    fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'ALIAS'
    },
    {
        name: 'OBJECT'
    },
    {
        name: 'DATETIME'
    },
    {
        name: 'FIELDVALUE'
    }
],
proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id: 'PendingModelProxy'
}
     }
});
```